# Using python regex to extract addresses from Craigslist rss feed

Tags: python, regex, rss, craigslist

I'm pulling my hair out trying to parse out a craigslist rss feed to extract location information.

I used [feedparser](http://www.feedparser.org/) to parse the script into into entries and entry descriptions. Unfortunately the address information is contained in irregular tags within the description section.

the addresses are contained in a section that looks like this:

```
<!-- CLTAG xstreet0=11832 se 318pl  -->
<!-- CLTAG xstreet1= -->
<!-- CLTAG city=auburn -->
<!-- CLTAG region=wa -->
11832 se 318pl
```

Feedparser doesn't like those CLTAGS. My attempt to capture the first line with regex looked like this:

```
addressStart = r'!-- CLTAG xstreet0='
addressEnd = r'-->'

prog = re.compile(addressStart(.*?)addressEnd)
result = prog.match(string)
```

...But that didn't work.  What am I doing wrong?  here is a link to the rss feed I'm working with 'http://seattle.craigslist.org/see/apa/index.rss'

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's some invalid syntax.  You cannot concatenate/format strings unless the strings are quoted.  Try:

```
addressStart = r'!-- CLTAG xstreet0='
addressEnd = r'-->'

prog = re.compile(addressStart + r'(.*?)' + addressEnd)
result = prog.match(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `search` instead of `match` (The reason is that the line starts with a `<` but you defined `addressStart` to begin with the `!`.  `search` finds a match anywhere in the string, while `match` only finds matches at the beginning.  Alternatively you could have redefined `addressStart` to contain the leading `<`.)

```
>>> import re;
>>> addressStart = r'!-- CLTAG xstreet0='
>>> addressEnd = r'-->'
>>> prog = re.compile(addressStart + "(.*?)" + addressEnd)
>>> string = "<!-- CLTAG xstreet0=11832 se 318pl  -->"
>>> result = re.search(prog, string)
>>> result
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1004806c0>
>>> result.group(1)
'11832 se 318pl  '
```